# Issue with AngularJS textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new at Angular.js, and I have a problem with a `textarea` element. When I write something and I click the **add this step** button , the text that I put in my text area is still there, but I don't know why.

HTML code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="stepAdd">Step</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"
  id="stepAdd" placeholder="Describe the solution to solve the problem step by step"
  ng-model="textStep" >
</textarea>
<a href="" class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="addStep(textStep)">Add this step</a>
```

Angular code :

```
  $scope.addStep = function(text) {

    if(text === undefined) return;

    var textFormat = text.trim();
    $scope.textStep = '';
    $scope.newDoc.steps.push({
       text: textFormat,
       editing : false,
       images : []
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  //make sure that you define $scope.newDoc
  $scope.newDoc = {
    steps: []

  }

  $scope.addStep = function(text) {
    if (text === undefined) return;
    var textFormat = text.trim();
    $scope.textStep = '';
    $scope.newDoc.steps.push({
      text: textFormat,
      editing: false,
      images: []
    });
  };

});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="stepAdd">Step</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="stepAdd" placeholder="Describe the solution to solve the problem step by step" ng-model="textStep"></textarea>
      <br/>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="addStep(textStep)">Add this step</a>


      <hr/>
      <h3>newDoc:</h3>
      <pre>  {{newDoc | json}}</pre>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Super, it works, I just added ng-controller="DocAddedCtrl" on my div, but it's strange because before it works without ng-controller, normally this controller is defined on my routing part